# Are more complex algorithms easier to break with timing attacks?

Tags: timing-attack, algorithm-design, side-channel-attack

Is there a point where increasing the complexity of an encryption algorithm will make it easier to break using a timing attack?

Or is there no connection here at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Timing attacks rely on operations which do not always take the same time to execute, depending on the processed data. For instance, on a typical software platform (say, a PC) implementing [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), all operations are 32-bit additions or rotations or bitwise combinations which take a constant time to execute, regardless of the actual operand values. SHA-256 is thus largely immune to timing attacks, because processing time, down to the nanosecond, depends only on the *length* of the input message, not on the values of the bits constituting the message. An attacker observing from the outside a SHA-256 computation would learn nothing about the hashed message, except possibly an estimate of the message length. On the other hand, a simple [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) implementation will leak information because the modular exponentiation incurs data-dependent and key-dependent costs (in a programmer's point of view, the code if full of "`if`" which operate on values computed from the input data and key).

"Complexity" of the algorithm is mostly irrelevant for that question. You can make a very complex algorithm out of operations which have no timing-related issue. Complexity is, in itself, a bad thing, since it makes analysis more complex (it is much harder to know whether the result is secure or not) and implies a higher implementation cost (in development time, and, often, in code size and execution speed).